# Preference menu showing on top of default view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I have the following code. It is supposed to create a preference view, when the user selects "settings" from the menu. It does this, however when the user selects "settings" the settings menu appears on top of my default view, like it has a transparent background. I have included what it looks like, when the settings menu is created.

[image: Application picture]
As you can see, my default view is blank except for "Large Text" in the middle of my screen, but the preferences menu, just displays on top of it.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
             getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsMenu())
             .addToBackStack(null)
             .commit();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you should be starting a new activity, rather than adding what I presume is a `PreferenceFragment` directly to your activity.

Or, you should be putting your existing UI ("Large Text") in a fragment that is being replaced via your `replace()` call. As it stands, it would appear that your existing UI is not in a fragment, or at least not in one identified as `android.R.id.content`.

Comment: Thanks. That makes more sense. (it also helps clean up my code too). I ended up putting my "large text"  in a fragment,  and it works well.